# Python 3 OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: (Workaround)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime, indexoutofboundsexception

Encountered an error today involving importing a CSV file with dates.  The file has known quality issues and in this case one entry was "3/30/3013" due to a data entry error.

Reading other entries about the OutOfBoundsDatetime error, datetime's upper limit maxes out at 4/11/2262.  The suggested solution was to fix the formatting of the dates.  In my case the date format is correct but the data is wrong.

Applying numpy logic:

```
df['Contract_Signed_Date'] = np.where(df['Contract_Signed_Date']>'12/16/2017',
    df['Alt_Date'],df['Contract_Signed_Date'])
```

Essentially if the file's 'Contract Signed Date' is greater than today (being 12/16/2017), I want to use the Alt_Date column instead.  It seems to work except when it hits the year 3013 entry it errors out.  Whats a good pythonic way around the out of bounds error?

Comment: Contract_Signed_Date is available in the dataframe as a string?

Comment: Bill, yes I can do: df['Contract_Signed_Date'].astype(str) but
df.Contract_Signed_Date.dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') gives me an error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values."  Using date_time gets me back to out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps hideously *un*pythonic but it appears to do what you want.

Input, file arthur.csv:

```
input_date,var1,var2
3/30/3013,2,34
02/2/2017,17,35
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

target_date='2017-12-17'
for_pandas = StringIO()
print ('input_date,var1,var2,alt_date', file=for_pandas) #new header
with open('arthur.csv') as arthur:
    next(arthur) #skip header in csv
    for line in arthur:
        line_items = line.rstrip().split(',')
        date = '{:4s}-{:0>2s}-{:0>2s}'.format(*list(reversed(line_items[0].split('/'))))
        if date>target_date:
            output = '{},{},{},{}'.format(*['NaT',line_items[1],line_items[2],date])
        else:
            output = '{},{},{},{}'.format(*[date,line_items[1],line_items[2],'NaT'])
        print(output, file=for_pandas)
for_pandas.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(for_pandas, parse_dates=['input_date', 'alt_date'])
print (df)
```

Output:

```
0        NaT     2    34  3013-30-03
1 2017-02-02    17    35         NaT
```